# South/Django: Schema migrations default value for existing entries

Tags: python, django, migration, schema, django-south

I want to add a BooleanField to an existing model, with default=False and that all already existing objects in my table get a True value in that field.

This is: I want all my existing objects to have my new attribute on True, but from now every new object has this value at False by default.

I tried rolling back my migration, setting the "keep_default" on True, migrate again but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new field with `default=False`, create the schemamigration as usually `--auto` and run it, then code a [datamigration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html) for changing the value to `True` for all existing objects and run it, that is all :D